# trouble showing already existing files jQuery File Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-file-upload

I've been beating my head over this for quite a while now, so I think it's time I reach out for help.  I have some already existing code that uses the jQuery File Uploader plugin, allowing me to upload files to my webserver.  The trouble I am having is listing files that already exist on the web server.

Here is my initialization **code that runs at the client**:

```
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            disableImageResize: false,
            url: '/api/upload',
            done: function (e, data) { // data is checked here }
        });

        // Load existing files:
        $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            context: $('#fileupload')[0],
            data: { action: "FileList", blob: "uts", path: "Unit 14/Binaries/" }
        }).always(function (e, data) {
            $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
        }).done(function (result) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                .call(this, $.Event('done'), { result: result });
        });
```

Now, I am trying to return a list of pre-existing files on the server side that matches the [JSON response akin to the documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#using-jquery-file-upload-ui-version-with-a-custom-server-side-upload-handler). My ASP.NET **code on the server side** is as follows (with two bogus files called "Something" and "SomethingElse" using my [FilesStatus class](http://pastebin.com/VqpHxjGW)).

```
    // Get a list of files from 
    private void FileList(HttpContext hc)
    {
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); 
        List<FilesStatus> fs_list = new List<FilesStatus>();

        fs_list.Add(new FilesStatus("Something", 124));
        fs_list.Add(new FilesStatus("SomethingElse", 124));

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");
        hc.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"files.json\"");
        var result = new { files = fs_list.ToArray() };
        hc.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
        hc.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    }
```

In the "done" function of the AJAX code, I see **what I believe is the proper response** on the client side.  Here, you can see the format in my Javascript debugger (i.e., a top level "files" that is an array):

[image]

These files do not get populated in to the file list, though. The code that I marked "//data is checked here" in the main done() function shows that the array can be accessed as "data.result.files" NOT "data.files." I can change ".call(this, $.Event('done'), { result: result });" to ".call(this, $.Event('done'), { files: result.files });" so that "data.files" is the location of the file array, but this does not solve the problem.  I can't seem to get any pre-existing files to load in to the list.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overwriting the done() method where I have:

```
done: function (e, data) { // data is checked here }
```

I did this for debugging, but apparently it blocks the pre-existing file list from being loaded and calling the download template.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change the line:

```
hc.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(result));
```

into

```
hc.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(fs_list.ToArray()));
```

It looks like the serializer is taking the variable name into account when you are serializing your file descriptions. The 'result' JSON object should disappear from the response.

Comment: I think that "result" simply comes from the fact that the parameter of the "done" function is named "result."  This unfortunately did not help :\  thanks for your response though!

Comment: I solved my bug, and I can't give myself the bounty... so I'm just going to give it to you for trying to help me. Enjoy.